# Did I convert my Jquery event listener into Javascript properly? I don't understand how the Javascript works without targeting the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert jquery into javascript. My app is a simple to do list and I'm targeting a button with an id called #clear-completed. Whenever I click that button on my app, it deletes the completed todo items, but I don't understand where it is being targeting in my new Javascript code.

Here is the original Jquery code

```
$('#footer').on('click', '#clear-completed', this.destroyCompleted.bind(this));
```

So I changed it to Javascript and this code worked

```
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
      footer.addEventListener('click', this.destroyCompleted.bind(this))
```

What I don't understand is what happened the the #clear-completed id and how does my new javascript code still work, even though I am not specifying to target the #clear-completed button?

Here is the code for the destroyCompleted function

```
destroyCompleted: function () {
            this.todos = this.getActiveTodos();
            this.filter = 'all';
            this.render();
        },
```

In the debugger it runs through the activeTodos function, but I don't see anywhere where the id #clear-completed is targeted?

```
getActiveTodos: function () {
            return this.todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return !todo.completed;
            });
        },
        getCompletedTodos: function () {
            return this.todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return todo.completed;
            });
        },
```

Did I write my Jquery into Javascript properly? Or did I miss something?

Also, if the id had more than one event listener how would you code that properly? for example

```
$('#todo-list')
                .on('change', '.toggle', this.toggle.bind(this))
                .on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this))
                .on('keyup', '.edit', this.editKeyup.bind(this))
                .on('focusout', '.edit', this.update.bind(this))
                .on('click', '.destroy', this.destroy.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent JavaScript would be:

```
document.querySelector('#footer').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const element = event.target.closest('#clear-completed');

  if (
    event.currentTarget !== element && 
    event.currentTarget.contains(element)
  ) {
    this.destroyCompleted(event);
  }
});
```

The signature [`$(target).on(event, selector, handler)`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) that you're using is called a delegated event handler, so the `handler` is invoked on the `target` element as you have correctly reproduced, but it is only invoked when the event targets an element matching `selector` which is descendant of `target`, not including `target` itself.

Matching the selector is reproduced above by checking that [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) the element returned by [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) [`.closest(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

You could even break this logic out into a helper function to make it more readable:

```
document.querySelector('#footer').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const matches = selector => {
    const element = event.target.closest(selector);

    return (
      event.currentTarget !== element &&
      event.currentTarget.contains(element)
    );
  };

  if (matches('#clear-completed')) {
    this.destroyCompleted(event);
  }
});
```

Since you need this pattern multiple times, it makes sense to move it into another reusable function:

```
function delegate (target, type, selector, handler) {
  const matches = event => {
    const element = event.target.closest(selector);

    return (
      event.currentTarget !== element &&
      event.currentTarget.contains(element)
    );
  };

  target.addEventListener(type, event => {
    if (matches(event)) {
      handler(event);
    }
  });
}

const element = document.querySelector('#todo-list');

delegate(element, 'change', '.toggle', e => this.toggle(e));
delegate(element, 'dblclick', 'label', e => this.edit(e));
delegate(element, 'keyup', '.edit', e => this.editKeyup(e));
delegate(element, 'focusout', '.edit', e => this.update(e));
delegate(element, 'click', '.destroy', e => this.destroy(e));
```

Comment: @Kaiido thanks. I highly doubt OP's case deals with this particular scenario, but I'll try to address it with a more complicated alternative just in case.

Comment: @Kaiido look better?

Comment: ah this ended up working! But if you had more than one event listener for the same id, how would you write that code? I added the code block in the question for reference

Comment: @Brian how's that?

Comment: @Brian "it's not working" isn't a problem statement. Please describe what the current and expected behavior are. It would also be helpful to explain what changed between your usage of my answer before and after the edit I just made. Why did the initial answer work for you?

Comment: when I commented out the above code in my question, all of the eventlisteners stopped working and when I inputted your code, it basically did the exact same thing. When I double click, it should allow me to edit my input and when I click it should have deleted the input. It's a todo-list app, so that specific code should allow me to edit my li items and delete etc.

Comment: @Brian was it because you used `#footer` instead of `#todo-list`? Please be careful when copying and pasting code. You need be able to figure out how to adjust it to match your exact use case.

Comment: That's better ;-) and good finding on mine should have a stopped at target. Btw, yours still do differ in one case: https://jsfiddle.net/vu60tzbx/ though it's quite easy to fix.

Comment: @Kaiido that's bizarre... I wonder why jQuery chose not to match on descendants _and_ self. I'll go ahead and fix that.

Comment: @Brian was your problem perhaps caused by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61435915/revisions#rev9c5aa946-8bfc-4e64-a0a6-4a53e5e682a5)?

Comment: so looks like 90% of the code is working properly, except the dbclick isn't working. I'm not sure why I can't dbclick my label and edit what I typed based on the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You targeted '#clear-completed' in the jquery function by passing the argument,'#clear-completed', to your on event handler. Jquery on says:

https://api.jquery.com/on/
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

selector
Type: String

A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Comment: yeah so how do I convert that jquery code into javascript?

Comment: Different question then?

Comment: #clear-completed is the id of a button in my html file. I'm trying to convert my jquery into Javascript and the code I wrote above shows what I did and it works, but I don't understand why my Javascript code works because I don't target the clear completed id anywhere

Comment: so my javascript code looks fine then? so whenever I convert jquery eventlisteners back to javascript, I simply remove the #id or .class that is being targeted and just add the function like I did above? or does this only work for my specific case?